# Display an alert when there are no values in the field

Tags: jquery, html

what I want to do is to show the user an alert when he presses the submit button, but there are no selected values in the category field. How can I do that?

```
<input type="submit" value="Search">

<div class="styleselect">
    <select data-placeholder="Select a Category" name="cat" id="cat" class="select2"  multiple >
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="EN">England</option>
        <option value="GR">Greece</option>
        <option value="US">USA</option>
        <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there any selected index on the select box, if no show the alert.

```js
 function check()
   {
  var values = document.getElementById('cat').selectedIndex;
  if(values == '-1')
  {
   alert('PLease select atleast one'); 
   return false;
  }
   }
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Search" onClick="check()" >

<div class="styleselect">
                        <select data-placeholder="Select a Category" name="cat" id="cat" class="select2"  multiple >
                                  <option value="all">All</option>
                                 <option value="EN">England</option>
                                 <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                                 <option value="US">USA</option>
                                 <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                                </select>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do It Simply Just Add "required" keyword in every field like

```
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

> Note: The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in
>   Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using javascript [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) function and put a check for if value is selected or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var option = $('#cat').val();
    if(!option) {
      alert("Please select a country!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">

<div class="styleselect">
  <select data-placeholder="Select a Category" name="cat" id="cat" class="select2"  multiple >
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="EN">England</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="US">USA</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the required tag to your html element. then add an option with value=""

```
 <select required data-placeholder="Select a Category" name="cat" id="cat" class="select2"  multiple >
 <option value="">Choose value</option>
```